# Subquery returned more than 1 value. (problem)

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

the variable @teste has multiple solutions so i can't put them in a single variable. i am not sure how can i do this subquery. i want grab the formula and only change for certain names (which have different RealTV values). can someone help me pls?

````
//table operacao_3//      //table Operacao_1

|nom |RealTV| PrevTV     |   coluna      |    TV
 joao  320     NUll       Dias_Uteia_mes       22   
 luis  100     NUll       Dias_Uteis_Trab      6  
 Joana 50      Null

declare @teste int
declare @div int
set @div = (select (select TV from operacao_1 where coluna = 'dias_uteis_mes')/(select TV from operacao_1 where coluna = 'dias_uteis_trab'))
set @teste =  @div * (select Realtv from operacao_3 where nome = 'joao' and nome = 'luis')
Update operacao_3 set PrevTV = @teste```
````

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: hi. i edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've shortened the naming for my own testing purposes but you should be able to translate across

```
DECLARE @mes INT,
        @trab INT

SELECT @mes = TV FROM Table2 WHERE Coluna = 'mes'
SELECT @trab = TV FROM Table2 WHERE Coluna = 'trab'

UPDATE
    Table1
SET
    PrevTV = (@mes / @trab) * RealTV
WHERE
    Name IN ('Joao', 'Luis')
```

It essentially reads like this:

From Table1, get all the rows where the names are any of {the names}, then for each row returned, set the value of PrevTV to be the result of this calculation for this row.

This will update each individual with their own calculated values, there they are specified in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE`

Comment: yeah it should be an or. basically it's am trying to divide Dias_Uteis_mes/Dias_Uteis_Trab multiply by RealTV  and insert into PrevTV  for those two names, but RealTV changes values.

Comment: it is that.Thx!